# Как добавить сторонние файлы в проект?

Tags: java

Имеется проект и изображения, которые в нем отображаются. После создания *.jar файла изображения открываются в проекте, если их расположить рядом с ним. Как сделать так чтобы они были в jar файле?

Comment: Почитайте про ресурсы.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался методом MyClas.class.getResourceAsStream().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Важно прочитать 10ю главу первого тома Хорстамана, раздел "Упаковка приложений" и вынести, что для доступа к файлам в таком случае нужно использовать `MyClass.class.getResource()` и при сборке JAR-a включать туда используемые ресурсы.